# How to set predefined options for a function parameter in PHP?

Tags: php, function, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm wondering if it's possible to set predefined options for a function parameter in PHP8. I've only been abled to find setting a default option but that's not what I'm looking for. One simple use-case I have for this is the following.

```
function runQuery($query, $values = NULL, $returnValue = NULL){
    if ($returnValue == 'numRows'){
        //query will run here and return the number of rows that are selected
    } elseif ($returnValue == 'getAffectedRows'){
        //query will run here and return the number of affected rows (for example to check if a create, update or delete is succesfull)
    } elseif ($returnValue == 'getLastInsertID'){
        // query will run and return the ID of the inserted row
    } else {
        // query will execute without any returns
    }
}
```

Now when writing code a mistake can easily be made when entering a string as the returnValue. For example when not using a capital letter or just a typo. Also the IDE doesn't recognize what the options are. This can also create a lot of errors when refactoring.

I'm having an idea of calling the option for the returnValue in a way like below, but don't really know how to implement it. Or if it's even possible. (Most IDE's would be abled to find the possibilities here, like calling any instance of a class with a function or a variable of an instance)

```
runQuery('SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = ?', 5, $this->returnValue()->numRows());
```

Another idea I'm having is below but haven't found any information if something like this is possible either.

```
function runQuery($query, $values=NULL, $returnValue = ('numRows' || 'getAffectedRows' || 'getLastInsertID' || 'none')){
    //same code here as in first code snippet
}
```

If anybody can help out, you're welcome! Also idea's on how to tackle this issue looking to the maintainability of your code. Especially when the codebase get's large and you need to change functions set up like this, while they are used on many places throughout your codebase.

Comment: Do you know [enum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.enumerations.php)?

Comment: @shingo I did not. Can you elaborate a bit more on how to approach it. Right now I have an enum set up above the class called `returnValues`. inside the `runQuery` function  I have the parameter `returnValues $returnValue`.  Then for each option another function declared inside of it. And ending with a `match($returnValue){ returnValues::numRows => numRows(), and so on }`. Is it possible to put the functions somewhere in the match part, like how an if-else behaves? Thank you so much already for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You can use `swtich($returnValue){...}` statement or `if($returnValue == returnValues::numRows){...}` statement as usual.

Comment: Here's a match version: https://3v4l.org/3QetC#v8.2.11